# Get the length of the longest spline in Geometry Nodes

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes, vertex-colors, splines

I'm working on a tree that needs to have a vertex color gradient depending on how far each vertex is along the branches of the tree, normalized in a 0-1 range.

To do this I'm trying to get the length of the longest spline with geometry nodes. I'm using shortest edge paths node to generate a tree structure, and trying to find what spline among the ones generated that is the longest.

How would I go about doing this in geometry nodes?

Comment: Have you tried a *Spline Length node connected to a *Attribute Statistic* node? The *Max* output is the length of the longest spline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Spline Length** node with **Attribute Statistic** node and its **Max** output value to get the maximum length amongst the splines.

To isolate the *length* and *index* of the Spline and populate with it **Attribute fields** you have to perform a length ***comparison*** and then ***multiply*** the result by the respective index. I have also included a Spline separation in case you need it:

[image]

Here is the *Max Length Spline* **Group Node** set up:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works great.

Comment: @Adkopras You're welcome!